# Launch system tray applet from i3blocks blocklett?

Tags: i3

Using i3wm and i3blocks.
I have the network manager and pulse audio applets running along side. I am wondering if there is a way to launch those applet from a block.

Anyone done this or have seen this done?

Answer (score 1):

I have Networkmanager applet running on the status bar in i3. The only line I needed to add in the i3 config file is:

```
exec --no-startup-id nm-applet
```

It give me a nice icon, in the status bar which is clickable and allows me to choose the Wifi Network, I would like to join.